# Feature scaling for a big dataset

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, data-science

I am trying to use a deep learning model for time series prediction, and before passing the data to the model I want to scale the different variables as they have widely different ranges.

I have normally done this "on the fly": load the training subset of the data set, obtain the scaler from the whole subset, store it and then load it when I want to use it for testing.

Now the data is pretty big and I will not load all the training data at once for training.

How could I go to obtain the scaler? A priori I thought of doing a one-time operation of loading all the data just to calculate the scaler (normally I use the sklearn scalers, like StandardScaler), and then load it when I do my training process.

Is this a common practice? If it is, how would you do if you add data to the training dataset? can scalers be combined to avoid that one-time operation and just "update" the scaler?

Comment: _I am trying to use_...  Is there a chance that you could edit your post to include some part of this in the form of a [mcve]?  Without some specific problem you have encountered, that can be answered in concise fashion, this becomes a consulting job.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`StandardScaler` in `scikit-learn` is able to calculate the mean and std of the data in incremental fashion (for small chunks of data) by using [`partial_fit()`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler.html#sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler.partial_fit):

> **partial_fit(X, y=None)**
>
> Online computation of mean and std on X for later scaling. All of X is
>   processed as a single batch. This is intended for cases when fit is
>   not feasible due to very large number of n_samples or because X is
>   read from a continuous stream.

You will need two passes on the data:-

- One complete pass (can be in batches, calling `partial_fit()` to calculate the mean and std),
- Other pass on the data that you send ahead to the deep learning framework to `transform()` it on the fly.

Sample example:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
scaler = StandardScaler()

# First pass
# some_generator can be anything which reads the data in batches
for data in some_generator:
    scaler.partial_fit(data)

    # View the updated mean and std variance at each batch
    print(scaler.mean_)
    print(scaler.var_)


# Second pass
for data in some_generator:
    scaled_data = scaler.transform(data)

    # Do whatever you want with the scaled_data
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! For the reply and application example. As a side note for editing, the second print should print scaler.std_.